# Enum type set to an int array

Tags: java, arrays, enums, int

basically what i am trying to do is to set each spot in my maze to a specific enumerated type based on a random number i.e i randomly place 10 walls on the maze and those 10 spaces would be wall enum types. This is the code i have so far, and i cant figure out how to get it to work.

```
public enum CellType {
   CHEESE, OPEN, WALL, VISITED, MOUSE
}

public class Cell {

private Color color;
private ImageIcon image;
CellType type;


public Color getColor() {
    return color;
}
public void setColor(Color color) {
    this.color = color;
}
public ImageIcon getImage() {
    return image;
}
public void setImage(ImageIcon image) {
    this.image = image;
}
public CellType getType() {
    return type;
}
public void setType(CellType type) {
    this.type = type;
}
```

}

```
maze = new int[row][col];       
Random randomMaze = new Random();
for (int ran = 0; ran <= numWalls ; ran++)
    maze[randomMaze.nextInt(maze.length)][randomMaze.nextInt(maze.length)].setType(WALL);
```

Comment: It's possible for the same cell to be picked more than once, which would result in fewer than 10 walls.  One way to fix this would be: `if (maze[randomMaze.nextInt(maze.length)][randomMaze.nextInt(maze.length)].getType().equals(WALL)) ran--;` before the set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`maze` should be a 2D array of `Cell`s, not a 2D array of `int`s.